# every time i try to upload an image from django admin i get this error : "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed''

Tags: django, django-models

everytime i try to upload an image from django admin i get the error the , for the first time ive set the default value to temporary but then i changed it to None and i still see the default=temporary in django admin 
I dont know what to do please help <3 and I dont know why the error refers to FOREIGN KEY while i only have 1 model

this is my **model.py :**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager


class customMemberManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, mobileNumber, name, familyName, password, nationalCode, image, **other_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('YOU MUST ENTER VALID EMAIL')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, mobileNumber=mobileNumber, name=name, image=image, familyName=familyName,
                          password=password,
                          nationalCode=nationalCode, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, mobileNumber, name, familyName, image, password, nationalCode, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('superuser must be is_staff set to True')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('superuser must be is_superuser set to True')
        return self.create_user(email, mobileNumber, name, familyName, password, nationalCode, image, **other_fields)


class Members(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Members'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    familyName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    nationalCode = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    mobileNumber = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='register_image/', blank=True,default=None)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = customMemberManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'mobileNumber'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['nationalCode', 'familyName', 'name', 'email',]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.__str__()
```

this is my **admin.py :**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from registerapp.models import Members
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


class UserAdminConfig(UserAdmin):
    search_fields = ('email', 'name', 'mobileNumber',)
    list_filter = ('email', 'name', 'mobileNumber', 'nationalCode',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    list_display = ('email', 'familyName', 'mobileNumber', 'nationalCode', 'is_active', 'is_staff')
    fieldsets = (
        ('User information', {'fields': ('email','name', 'familyName',  'mobileNumber', 'image','password', 'nationalCode')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'groups')}),

    )

    add_fieldsets = [(None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('email', 'name', 'familyName', 'mobileNumber', 'password', 'nationalCode')
    })]


admin.site.register(Members, UserAdminConfig)
```

and this is my **settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and my **urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from registerapp import views

app_name = 'registerapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin', admin.site.urls),
    path('login', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    # path('sendfile', views.sendFile, name='sendfile'),
    path('logout', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('success', views.sucessfull, name='success'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides setting `blank=True` (used by form validations), also set `null=True` (used for database constraints).

Comment: i tried but didnt work :( @physicalattraction

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace of the error that you're seeing to the original post?

Comment: solved my problem in another way ty for help
@physicalattraction

Answer (score 0):

have you set  code below to your settings.py?

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "appname.Members"

add this code , clear migirations , run makemigrations and migrate again .

Note: use singular names for your models . Member not Members